# Unresolved variable SdkBridge -- react native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, facebook

Hi i update my react native project from 0.59.9 to 0.64.2, but it it not finding the next import

```
import {NativeModules, Platform} from 'react-native';

const SdkBridge = NativeModules.SdkBridge;
```

The id shows the next

> Unresolved variable SdkBridge

Someone knows what is the alternative

Comment: try this way : const { SdkBridge } = ReactNative.NativeModules;

Comment: Yes, it worked, but what is the difference between the first and second (import ReactNative, {Platform} from 'react-native';

const {SdkBridge} = ReactNative.NativeModules;
). it is the same @sidverma

Comment: Great! do upvote so that it reaches large audience .
Read more here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android#module-name